# Phantomjs apply styling after page breaks

Tags: html, css, phantomjs, page-break-inside

I am generating a PDF Report using phantomjs.

Below is my CSS that avoids splitting text across two pages. It moves the entire line to the new page as expected.

```
.columns {
    page-break-inside:avoid;
}
```

I wish to insert a margin and border at the beginning of each page, but haven't found a way to apply styling after these page breaks occur. Adding something like below adds the styling I desire to every column class, but I only want it applied to the first occurrence on each page.

```
@media print {
  .columns {
    border-top: .1rem solid #f0f1f4;
    border-radius: .2rem;
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
}
```